# async inside a for loop nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, for-loop, asynchronous

I am trying to access an api and I will have to run the api calls several times based on the page numbers I need to iterate, the following is the code which I am using and how can I get the all the response pushed into an array.

as nodeJs is single threaded It is not waiting for the responses from the api.
How can I can tackle this and ensure all the response values are being pushed into an array

Inside the for loop I want the final array which has all the values of the api response. So, I check the total page value and response page Number if that matches which means that will be the last page and I push the array to another function but when I do that it does not have all the values because nodejs does not wait for the api response.

```
const fs = require('fs');
var pepKey = 'asdfasdfasd';
var pepResponse;

var pepTimecards = [];
pep();


function pep(){
    var options = {
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
        },
        agentOptions: {
            pfx: fs.readFileSync('./certificate/asdfsdaf.p12'),
            passphrase: 'asdasdsda'
        }
    };

    request.get('https://source.asdfasdf.io/api/organisations/asdfasdf/timecard_keys?timecard_type=Flex',options,  (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) { return console.log(err); }
      pepResponse = JSON.parse(body)

    pepTimecards = pepResponse.data;
      if(pepResponse.pages > 1){
         for(let i=2;i<=pepResponse.pages;i++){

            var url = 'https://source.`pepme`.io/api/organisations/sdfsadf/timecard_keys?timecard_type=Flex&page='+pageNo;
            request.get(url,options,  (err, res, body) => {
                if (err) { return console.log(err); }
                body = JSON.parse(body)
                pepTimecards = pepTimecards.concat(body.data)
                if(pepResponse.pages == body.page){
                    console.log(pepResponse.pages)
                    console.log(body.page +"body page")
                    console.log(pepTimecards)
                }
              });


        }


      }else{

      }  
    });
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `request-promise` library and use `async/await` syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the request-promise library which supplies promisified versions of the request library.  Then, you can use async/await in your  `for` loop to serialize your operations:

**Newer answer to go with the edited code in the OP's question**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const rp = require('request-promise');
const pepKey = 'asdfasdfasd';

pep().then(pepTimecards => {
    // the timecard data is valid in here
    console.log(pepTimecards);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});


async function pep() {
    let timecards = [];
    const options = {
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
        },
        agentOptions: {
            pfx: fs.readFileSync('./certificate/asdfsdaf.p12'),
            passphrase: 'asdasdsda'
        },
        json: true,
        uri: 'https://source.asdfasdf.io/api/organisations/asdfasdf/timecard_keys?timecard_type=Flex'
    };

    let pepResponse = await rp(options);

    timecards = pepResponse.data;
    if (pepResponse.pages > 1) {
        for (let i = 2; i <= pepResponse.pages; i++) {
            options.uri = 'https://source.`pepme`.io/api/organisations/sdfsadf/timecard_keys?timecard_type=Flex&page='+pageNo;
            let body = await rp(url, options);
            // add body.data onto the existing array
            timecards.push(...body.data);
        }
    } else {

    }
    console.log(pepResponse.pages)
    console.log(timecards)
    return timecards;
}
```

---

**Prior Answer before OP edited the code in their question:**

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

// I'm assuming this is some sort of method definition on a class, otherwise it needs the function keyword
async pageno(pageNo) {
    for (let i=2;i<=pepResponse.pages;i++){
        try {
            options.uri = 'https://test/timecard_keys?timecard_type=asdas&page='+pageNo;
            // let request-promise parse the json for you automatically
            options.json = true;
            let body = await rp(options);
            pepTimecards = pepTimecards.concat(body.data)
            if (pepResponse.pages == body.page){
                console.log(pepResponse.pages)
                console.log(body.page +"body page")
                console.log(pepTimecards)
            }
        } catch(e) {
            // decide what to do for error handling
            // this will log and rethrow so the caller will get a rejected promise
            console.log(e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
    // return some value here to be the resolved value of the returned promise
    return pepTimecards;
}
```

In your code, it is not clear where the `options`, `pepTimecards`, `pepResponse` variables are declared.  They should probably be declared as local variables here or passed in to the function and/or returned from your function.

---

**Summary of modifications:**

1. Add `async` to method declaration so we can use `await`.
2. Load request-promise library into `rp` variable
3. Add `options.json = true` to the let the request-promise library parse the JSON result for us automatically
4. Change `rp()` to just use the options structure (add URL to that)
5. Add try/catch to catch any errors from the `await`, log them, then rethrow so `pageno()` will return a promise that rejects if there is an error (you can customize the behavior when there's an error if desired)
6. Add a return value so there is meaningful resolved value to the promise (you should not be using side-effect programming as it is now (modifying variables that are not passed in, declared locally or returned).

**Things for you still to fix:**

1. Stop using side-effect programming where you modify free variables that aren't passed in, aren't declared locally and aren't returned.  This is a bad way to design code.  You don't show enough overall context from the calling code or where these other variables are defined to make a concrete recommendation on how it should be done.
2. Decide what your error handling strategy is if there's an error on one of the requests and implement that strategy and proper handling.

Comment: the rp.get function is not an async function. I get the error which says await is only valid in async function.

Comment: @yosup - `rp.get()` is asynchronous and returns a promise, therefore you can use `await` on it.  I'm not sure what else your comment means.  You need the `async` in front of the `pageno()` declaration in order to use `await`.

Comment: I get the error

     let body = await rp.get(url, options)
                       ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3

Comment: @KevinB I am not even accessing pageno(). How does that even matter if it has async before it

Comment: @yosup - Your `pageno()` method declaration needs `async` in front of it like I show.  If you need more help, then show us more context around this, including the rest of the class definition.  You can ONLY use `await` inside a function declared as `async`.

Comment: @yosup - If you still need further help, then show us the code you are currently trying that gives this error AND show us the entire class definition that this is part of.  Add the latest version you are trying as an edit onto the end of your question (don't change what you already have, add the new code onto the end of the question).  Use the "edit" link under your question to modify it.  We're willing to help you more, but need to see what exactly you're trying - we can't fix code we can't see.

Comment: I have  edited the code in my question. You can check now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @yosup - I've added a new version of the code to the beginning of my answer.  In the future, when you want to show different code in your question, please do NOT remove the code that was in the original question because answers have already been written to that code and it's not fair to people that already attempted to help you to invalidate their answers entirely by editing your question.  Instead, add the new code onto the end of your question, leaving the original part of the question intact.